# Angular development environment and production environment

Tags: angular, environment-variables, development-environment, production-environment

I have some variables that in the Rest service, like the API for example, that works only on the localhost.

I want to set up the project to production. But those variables have to be different from my localhost and form my production site.

How do I configure that? git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place for these type of constants is environment.ts and environment.prod.ts. 
For development put your constants in envirnonment.ts and for production put in environment.prod.ts

Comment: Yeah, thanks you very much! . Can you Upvote my question?